# Why does the IPython error about "input" mention "raw_input"?

Tags: python, ipython

I have following line of code to accept Identifiers:

```
security = input("Insert ID")
```

This works great on my python. However when I send the notebook to a colleague, this error occurs:

```
StdinNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-324a5244d6ce> in <module>
      1 ## Insert NIM/PREL or active Bond here
----> 2 security = input("Insert Bond ID or Figi # -- e.x. 025816CH0 Corp, BBG012JJ3534 ") #BQ3149326 credit ag #BQ4561651 jag #025816CH0 AMEX #BR0344159 PREL EXAMPLE #BR1139871 PREL INR

C:\axy\py\environments\quant2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py in raw_input(self, prompt)
    853         if not self._allow_stdin:
    854             raise StdinNotImplementedError(
--> 855                 "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests."
    856             )
    857         return self._input_request(str(prompt),

StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.
```

What could be causing this mis match?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what you're asking exactly. If I've misunderstood, by all means [edit] to fix it. And LMK if you do so I can update my answer. I assume you've read and understood the error message but you're confused about the details.

Answer (score 0):

IPython refers to `input` as `raw_input` for historical reasons.

Python 2's `raw_input` was renamed `input` in Python 3. For more info, see [What's the difference between `raw_input()` and `input()` in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/4518341)

IPython used to support Python 2 and 3, so it had code like this:

```
if PY3:
    ...
    builtin_mod.input = self.raw_input
else:
    ...
    builtin_mod.raw_input = self.raw_input
```

then they dropped Python 2 support in version 6.0 so it became:

```
...
builtin_mod.input = self.raw_input
```

[Here's the diff on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/commit/5fb9e68987187ffdd2b320a92606b5d3e4088669#diff-005dc034747cf08fb561886cbb035ae39d21a32d013ff2608e5fe3dc418f64eeL184-R186)